# How to unit test if an event performs a segue

Tags: unit-testing, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

How to unit test if an event like touch up inside on a given button would call a specific segue? I know I can call the segue directly and check for the result but I want to test IF the event would perform the segue, in other words, if the link in storyboard is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was your doubts, but you can check if this is correct segue

Try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Claudia, but I'm referring to unit test code. I want to test the hook between an event and a segue.